# Get old or user variable value on form after custom request validation error, view with two different forms

Tags: php, laravel, forms, validation

**EDIT:**

Your solutions are working for text inputs and textareas, but checkboxes are not working correctly for me.

This was my original checkbox:

```
{{ Form::checkbox('active', true, (isset($user->active)) ? old($user->active) : true, ['class' => 'custom-control-input', 'id' => 'active']) }}
```

I've tried a lot of possible solutions like adding `old('active', isset($user) ? $user->active: true)` instead, but when an error occurs I lose the values from this input. On the controller I was checking this, but if I change the input to the 'new solution' active is always false on my db:

```
if(!array_key_exists('active', $validated)){
    $validated = array_add($validated, 'active', '0');
}
```

**ORIGINAL QUESTION (PARTIALLY RESOLVED):**

I have one blade view call **edit** with **two** **forms**, but each one is calling his own method/route. One form is for edit/store the user and the other is a form in a modal to change the user password. When I change the password and no validation error happens, the other form still has all of his values that is getting from **old()** or $user variable via index method. But if for example the passwords do not match, a validation error occurs, and the values from the edit/store user form disappear.

Forms are pretty simple (remember, they are on the same view, and the one that is giving me problems is the edit/create one), and each one call a different method from **UserController**

**Form 1 for edit users (simplified)**

```html
@if($user->exists)
    {{ Form::model($user, ['route' => ['users.update', $user], 'class' => 'needs-validation', 'novalidate'=>'']) }}
    @method('PATCH')
@else
    {{ Form::model($user, ['route' => ['users.store'], 'class' => 'needs-validation', 'novalidate'=>'']) }}
    @method('POST')
@endif
@csrf
<div class="form-group">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        {{ Form::label('cif', __('users.cif'), ['class' => 'form-label']) }}
        {{ Form::text('cif', (isset($user->cif)) ? old($user->cif) : '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'required','maxlength'=>'12', 'minlength'=>'9']) }}
        {{ Form::hidden('validate','', ['class' => 'form-control', 'required', 'id'=>'validate']) }}
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        {{ Form::label('name', __('users.name'), ['class' => 'form-label']) }}
        {{ Form::text('name', (isset($user->name)) ? old($user->name) : '', ['class' => 'form-control','required','maxlength'=>'255']) }}
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        {{ Form::label('initials', __('users.initials'), ['class' => 'form-label']) }}
        {{ Form::text('initials', (isset($user->initials)) ? old($user->initials) : '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'required','maxlength'=>'5']) }}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    {{ Form::label('province', __('users.province'), ['class' => 'form-label']) }}
    {{ Form::text('province', (isset($user->city)) ? $user->city->province->name  : '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'disabled'=>'']) }}
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**Form 2: Update password**

```html
<form id="change-password" action="{{route('users.change.password', $user)}}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="panel-tag">
                <p>Las contraseñas debe de coincidir y tener más de 8 carácteres</p>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Contraseña</label>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="new-password"  minlength="8">
                    @error('password')
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                        </span>
                    @enderror
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="password-confirmation" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Confirmar contraseña</label>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input id="password-confirmation" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password" minlength="8">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button id="change" type="submit" form="change-password" class="btn btn-primary">Confirmar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**UserController** I'm going to paste two methods, one for store/user, the other for change the password. Update method is very similar.

```php
public function store(StoreUserRequest $request) 
{
    if( $request['validate'] == 1 ){
        $validated = $request->validated();
        $validated['password'] = Hash::make($validated['password']);
        $id = DB::table('users')->insertGetId($validated);
        return redirect()->route('users.edit',['user'=>$id])->with('status', 'created');
    } else {
        return redirect()->back()->withInput()->with('status', 'error_dni');
    }

}

public function changePassword(PasswordUserRequest $request, User $user)
{ // HERE IS WHERE I THINK IS THE PROBLEM, IF VALIDATION FAILS (FOR EXAMPLE PASSWORD CONFIRM) VALUES FROM THE OTHER FORM DISAPPEAR AND IT DOESNT GET INTO THIS METHOD 
    $pass = Hash::make($request->password);
    $user->password = $pass;
    $action = $user->save();
    if ($action) {
       return redirect()->back()->with('status', 'change_password_ok');
    }
    return redirect()->back()->with('status', 'error_change_password');
}
```

**PasswordUserRequest** This is the request to validate the password form

```php
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'password' => 'required|string|confirmed'; 
    ];
}
```

The route would be something like:

`users/{user}/edit`

I've spent all day trying to fix this and still didn't found a solution. My english is not very good so please tell me if I'm not explaining something correctly and I will edit the question.

Thanks and hope that I can find a solution.

Comment: answer updated, dont mix codes lmao im using left-right hand-side operand

Comment: you are using Form::checkbox() the wrong way, not the old() functions xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

old values are from input name

```
<input type="text" name="input" value="{{old('input')}}"
```

example

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
  {{ Form::label('cif', __('users.cif'), ['class' => 'form-label']) }}
  {{ Form::text('cif', old('cif', $user->cif ?? ''), ['class' => 'form-control', 'required','maxlength'=>'12', 'minlength'=>'9']) }}
  {{ Form::hidden('validate','', ['class' => 'form-control', 'required', 'id'=>'validate']) }}
</div>
//$user->cif ?? '' <- left or right hand-side operand, return right-hand if left is null or undefined
//old('input', $user->cif ?? '') <- if old input available, use old input, if not, $user will be displayed
```

form::checkbox:

> 1. First argument : name
> 2. Second argument : value
> 3. Third argument : checked or not checked (true or false)
> 4. Fourth argument : additional attributes

note that value is attribute(value) and checked is attribute(checked)
then

```
{{ Form::checkbox('active', true, (isset($user->active)) ? $user->active : true, ['class' => 'custom-control-input', 'id' => 'active']) }}
//2nd parameter (true) will always set checkbox value to 1(true)
//(isset($user->active)) ? $user->active : true <- will set default to true (checked) if $user is null or undefined
//maybe try
{{ Form::checkbox('active', $user->active ?? false, $user->active ?? false) }}
//if $user != null, put $user->active else put false
//if $user != null, set checked value based on $user->active else put false
```

in html looks like this

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked">
```

then you need to add inline event `onchange="$(this).is(':checked') ? $(this).val(1) : $(this).val(0);"` in the 4th parameter of form::checkbox to change the default on runtime

Answer (score 0):

If I understood all correctly, you should do this way:

```
old('name', isset($user) ? $user->name : ''),
```

Here you trying to get old `name` input, and if it doesn't exist, in second parameter od `old` function you are getting default value, which is user's name in case of user exists

There is [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#old-input), which can help you to understand much more.